# bash tabbing for autocompletion escapes $

Tags: bash, bash-completion

In shell (`GNU bash, version 4.2.47(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)`), when I hit tab for autocompletion, the "$" is escaped after the variable name is completed, but if there is no completion then it just bells. E.g.

```
$ ls $JDK_H<tab>
```

results in

```
$ ls \$JDK_HOME (with a trailing space)
```

On an old GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu), it did not escape the "$" after completion which is what I would like.

Is there a way to get that old behavior without strong side-effects? My BASHOPTS and SHELLOPTS are:

```
# (indented for readability)
BASHOPTS=checkwinsize:cmdhist:expand_aliases:extglob:extquote
            :force_fignore:histappend:interactive_comments:login_shell
            :progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history
            :interactive-comments:monitor
```

Thanks. I am using SLES SP11.

--UPDATE. Other completions seem to work as usual, e.g. `cd` or `echo` do not escape the `$`. I also momentarily commented out `/etc/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` from my `/etc/bash.bashrc` which stopped $-escaping. So it appears like some kind of complete config issue.

Comment: Report a bug to SuSE.

Comment: I am not certain if this is a bug or a feature :-( I do know it is very frustrating

Comment: Why close? I see an infinite number of shell questions on SO, some indeed version related

Comment: The fact that many off-topic questions go unnoticed does not change the rules.  This is borderline for several reasons -- if it's a bug, you should be submitting a bug report; it's not directly programming-related; and you are not asking how to solve this in code. I also believe it is a duplicate, although I cannot locate the earlier similar question I saw.

Comment: Sure, np. I see several pointers saying it's a bug. (As an aside, I think of SO as a living ecosystem where what is appropriate use is keeps on getting refined by the community.)

Answer (score 6):

Recent bash versions introduced some compatibility issues regarding this. Try like this:

```
complete -r # temporarily disable all completion rules
shopt -s direxpand
```

Links to similar problems reported to the [bug-bash](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-bash) mail list:

- http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-01/msg00062.html
- http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-08/msg00176.html

Comment: I see nothing that's different from my bash 3. I saw see a huge number of configuration under `complete`; so I momentarily commented out `/etc/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` from `/etc/bash.bashrc` and now `cd` works just like `ls` etc. so it appears like some kind of `complete` config problem

Comment: forgot to add, `shopt -s direxpand` does not change this behavior

Comment: Updated by adding some links.

Comment: Thanks for the links and the tip. It claimed the issue was resolved in 4.2.45 but I am running bash 4.2.47 and still see it.