# How do I get bash tab-completion to stop escaping glob wildcards at the beginning of the argument?

Tags: bash, glob, tab-completion, bash-completion

When I try to use tab-completion in bash for a file glob pattern starting with either `?` or `*`, I get the list of completion options as intended, but then my command prompt is modified to escape the glob special character.

For example:

```
$ ls *.txt                  # tab-complete instead of enter
bar.txt  fib.txt  foo.txt
$ ls \*.txt                 # now my '*' is escaped
```

And:

```
$ ls ???.txt                # tab-complete
bar.txt  fib.txt  foo.txt
$ ls \?\?\?.txt             # please stop
```

How do I get it to stop escaping the special characters when I trigger tab-completion?

This doesn't happen when the `*` or `?` special character is not at the start of the pattern for completion:

```
$ ls f*.txt       # tab-complete
fib.txt  foo.txt
$ ls f*.txt       # my prompt doesn't change. This is what I want.
```

This problem seems very similar to:

- [bash tabbing for autocompletion escapes $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463052/bash-tabbing-for-autocompletion-escapes)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/70750/how-to-get-bash-to-stop-escaping-during-tab-completion

None of the solutions seem to address my problem, though.

Some info about my setup:

- My `~/.inputrc` contains (pretty much exclusively) `set editing-mode vi` and `set show-all-if-unmodified on`.
- I'm using `bash` version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).
- I uninstalled `bash-completion` because it was causing me another problem with tab-completion. (Tab-completion changed my prompt to use the first match rather than showing me the options.  I got the idea to uninstall it from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278449/439902 .)

Comment: An interesting problem, but  StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su] or possibly [unix.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the redirect.

Since I haven't reposted the question on either of those, I'll just leave a comment here that it turns out the problem is `show-all-if-unmodified`. I probably enabled it when I still had `bash-completion` installed. Without `bash-completion`, I want neither `show-all-if-unmodified` nor `show-all-if-ambiguous`.